# npm start failing on server (works on local host)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, deployment, server, mern

Error message received while trying to deploy on render:

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! code ENOENT
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! syscall open
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! path /opt/render/project/src/package.json
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! errno -2
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/render/project/src/package.json'
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

```
Jul 22 07:02:54 PM  npm ERR! enoent
```

Script in package.json looks like this

```
"scripts": {
  "install-server" : "cd server && npm install",
  "start-server": "cd server && node app.js",
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}


On render I put 'npm build' for build command and 'npm start' for start command.
```

Comment: Sounds like a deployment issue. What are you hosting this on?

Comment: @cyberwombat I'm hosting on render.com

Comment: please share your folder structure once.